# Replace master with branch

Tags: git

I have made multiple commits. Then I had to come back to the commit in the middle. Made changes there and created new branch. Now what I want to do is to skip (remove, delete) all other commits and use branch as the master version. But can't figure out how to do it.

Here is some explanation of the situation:

```
commit1 (latest)
commit2
commit3 (head pointing here)
other commits...
```

At point of `commit3`, I made changes and created new branch to push them.

Now I would like to make branch version as the main one, removing the `commit2` and `commit1`.

Comment: Do you want to make your new branch the default branch or change master so that it has exactly the same commits that your new branch currently has?

Comment: @8bittree i want the master to have the state of branch ( second scenario that u described)

Comment: Also, have you pushed commits 1 and 2 or are they only local?

Comment: Already pushed. Everything is pushed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've pushed, your least-likely-to-break-things option is probably `git revert`:

```
git checkout master
git revert commit1 commit2
git merge new-branch
git push
```

Note that this will result in master having exactly the same files as new-branch, but commit1 and commit2 will still be in master's history, along with two additional commits reverting their changes.

---

## NOT RECOMMENDED

If you really, really want to actually remove commits that you've already pushed from master, first, notify all your teammates that you're going to be probably breaking things, then use `git reset`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard commit3
git merge new-branch
git push -f
```

`--hard` will remove all the changes made by commit1 and commit2 from your filesystem. You can use `--soft` to preserve those changes in the filesystem, while still removing those commits.

You may want to point your teammates towards the documentation for [recovering from an upstream rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) (git reset points to that section when talking about using `reset --hard` on already pushed commits).